# What does an Audio Unit Host need to do to make use of non-Apple Audio Units?

Tags: macos, audiounit

I am writing an Objective-C++ framework which needs to host Audio Units. Everything works perfectly fine if I attempt to make use of Apple's default units like the DLS Synth and various effects. However, my application seems to be unable to find any third-party Audio Units (in /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components).

For example, the following code snippet...

```
CAComponentDescription tInstrumentDesc = 
     CAComponentDescription('aumu','dls ','appl');

AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &tInstrumentDesc, &mInstrumentNode);

AUGraphOpen(mGraph);
```

...works just fine. However, if I instead initialize `tInstrumentDesc` with `'aumu', 'NiMa', '-Ni-'` (the description for Native Instruments' Massive Synth), then `AUGraphOpen()` will return the `OSStatus` error `badComponentType` and the AUGraph will fail to open. This holds true for all of my third party Audio Units.

The following code, modified from the Audacity source, sheds a little light on the problem. It loops through all of the available Audio Units of a certain type and prints out their name.

```
ComponentDescription d;

d.componentType = 'aumu';
d.componentSubType = 0;
d.componentManufacturer = 0;
d.componentFlags = 0;
d.componentFlagsMask = 0;

Component c = FindNextComponent(NULL, &d);
while(c != NULL)
{
    ComponentDescription found;

    Handle nameHandle = NewHandle(0);

    GetComponentInfo(c, &found, nameHandle, 0, 0);

    printf((*nameHandle)+1);
    printf("\n");

    c = FindNextComponent(c, &d);
}
```

After running this code, the only output is `Apple: DLSMusicDevice` (which is the Audio Unit fitting the description `'aumu', 'dls ', 'appl'` above).

This doesn't seem to be a problem with the units themselves, as Apple's `auval` tool lists my third party Units (they validate too).

I've tried running my test application with `sudo`, and the custom framework I'm working on is in /Library/Frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was due to compiling for 64-bit. After switching to 32-bit, everything began to work as advertised. Not much of a solution I guess, but there you have it.

To clarify, I mean changing the XCode Build Setting `ARCHS` to "32-bit Intel" as opposed to the default "Standard 32/64-bit Intel".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm going to assume that you initialized `mGraph` by calling `NewAUGraph(&mGraph)` instead of just declaring it and then trying to open it. Beyond that, I suspect that the problem here is with your AU graph, not the AudioUnits themselves. But to be sure, you should probably try loading the AudioUnit manually (ie, outside of a graph) and see if you get any errors that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am initializing mGraph and doing all of the proper legwork outside of the code snippet I posted. Turns out, the issue was due to compiling for 64-bit. I just can't post a solution yet due to being a new user.