# My custom Audio Unit opens in AU Lab but not Garageband or Ableton

Tags: xcode, plugins, core-audio, audiounit

I created a filter AU in Xcode as a project for a signals class I'm taking,and I can open it just fine in AU Lab from my components folder, but I cant seem to open it in a DAW. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this? Could it be a setting in the .plist file? There is no error in the code because the AU works perfectly in AU lab. If anybody has an idea help would be much appreciated and I can supply any information you might need.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  My guess is GarageBand, Mainstage and others load audio unit plugins the old way (à la MacOS 9), using the obscure deprecated Resource stuff that I know nothing about (the file ending with .r, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/Rez.1.html).  AU Lab and auval load AU components using the AudioComponents key of the plist.  If you grabbed official sample codes, it is likely that all your 'Resource' configurations is screwed since the .r files are not even 'compiled' by the sample projects.  I will experiment.

Comment: Try building in 32-bit mode if you aren't. I had a similar issue a while back : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639815/what-does-an-audio-unit-host-need-to-do-to-make-use-of-non-apple-audio-units

Answer (score 4):

I made the investigation I mentioned in my comments thus I'm writing a real answer now.

I confirmed my suspicions.  In case you don't  have the  issue with 32/64 bits build mode (like others said), you may well have the same issue as I had.

GarageBand and Mainstage (presumably others) don't read the keys of the  `AudioComponents` key of the bundle's plist.  They only read the deprecated crappy Carbon resources.

I have a proof of this  (at least on my system:  Lion, GarageBand 6.0.5):

- most of the AU I've downloaded only provides Carbon resources and don't have `AudioComponents` key in their plist (because it was the way to go before Lion and only noob like me ignores this fact)
- as soon as I properly added the Carbon resources to my unit, it starts appearing in GarageBand and MainStage (youhou!)

If you started your project from a copy of TremoloUnit or some others project Apple provides, you must fix them because their projects are screwed.  Obviously, the poor soul who maintains them is as noob as I am about AudioUnit programming, he believed (like I did) that those horrible Carbon *things* from a dark age must be completely deprecated by now  and he unchecked them from the build phase.  Since the resulting AU loads fine in `AU Lab` and validates fines with `auval` he was happy and committed his work.

To fix the project, you must add the Resource source file (the one ending with `.r`) to the build phase (it is already in the project).  If you click on it from the file inspector, XCode will figure itself (from the file extension) that you want to build hideous Carbon Resources.
After that, you will certainly have obscure build failures because the *Rez search path* is wrong.  You must also double check that `.r` file describes the same things as your `AudioComponents` because Apple's sample project AUPinkNoise was broken on that topic (the 4 letters code of the sub-type had a mismatch between the plist and the .r resource source)

Congratulation to Apple to build a validation tool that just ignores how most Apple products currently load AudioUnit.

Comment: Where can you get the .r file for the TremoloUnit example? My copy of the project doesn't have it.

Comment: The .r file provided here seems to work: http://allthingsarcane.blogspot.com/2012/04/of-audio-units-and-xcode-43.html

Answer (score 1):

[This All Things Arcane article](http://allthingsarcane.blogspot.com/2012/04/of-audio-units-and-xcode-43.html) is a great place to start.

Additionally, for xcode 5.x and now current (2015-05) examples from Apple there are a few extra steps that may also help:
1. In "Build Settings, Apple LLVM  - Preprocessing" add the Preprocessor Macro "CA_USE_AUDIO_PLUGIN_ONLY=0" which enables the ability to use the old style entry point in your .r file and .exp file (allows you to add _SinSynthEntry as well as _SinSynthFactory)
2. Remove and re-add "AUDispatch.cpp" and "AUDispatch.h" to your project (this is to resolve the missing "CMgr_AudioUnitBase…" link references)
3. If you are building for OS X 10.8 or older you have to modify Apple's AUBase.cpp to carve out kAudioUnitProperty_NickName which was added in 10.9 conditionally compiling based on OS X version.  An example:

```
#if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_8)    //ADD ME!
    case kAudioUnitProperty_NickName:
        ca_require(inScope == kAudioUnitScope_Global, InvalidScope);
        outDataSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
        outWritable = true;
        break;
#endif                                                         //ADD ME!
```

Answer (score 0):

As @admsyn suggested, the issue is most likely that you are building a 64-bit plugin, which Xcode will do for you by default. You should either build a 32/64 bit Universal Binary (in both Debug *and* Release builds), or just 32-bit.

Also it probably helps to run `auval -v` to verify the AU, just to make sure that something isn't wrong.

Comment: As I said, I have the same issue and my unit does validate with auval completely (in both 32 bits and 64 bits mode).  They can be open in AU Lab (in both 32 bits and 64 bits mode).  They can never be loaded in Mainstage (neither in 32 bits nor 64 bits mode).  My Garageband can't be launched in 32 bits mode so I can only say it won't load my unit in 64 bits mode.  So this must be something else, at least for me and presumably for the author of the question.  I did not have the time to investigate the OS9 resource hypothesis.

Comment: huhu: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2276/_index.html  If Mainstage and GarageBand targets OS < Lion, they may not read the plist at all, as I feared.